# Ayuda con RegularExpressionValidator en Modal

Tags: asp.net

Tengo el siguiente modal, en el cual el usuario debe escribir obligatoriamente al menos 20 caracteres en un textbox para poder ejecutar el onclick de un button, el problema es que el control asp:RegularExpressionValidator no funciona y no quiero que el usuario oprima el boton con el textbox vacio

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalC" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title m-0 font-weight-bold text-danger" id="exampleModalLabel1">Titulo</h5>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<h6 style="float: left; width: 100%" class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">¿Esta seguro de eliminar la informacion?</h6>
<h6 style="float: left; width: 100%" class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-secondary">Justifique</h6>
<asp:TextBox ID="Just_c" runat="server" CssClass="fin_sC form-control" AutoComplete="off" Style="border-color: dodgerblue; text-transform: uppercase;" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="Just_c" ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{20,}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Se requieren al menos 20 caracteres" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="finS"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-secondary shadow-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
<button type="button" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm" runat="server" id="Send_C" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="finS" onserverclick="SendC_ServerClick">Aceptar</button>
</div>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
<button type="button" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm" runat="server" id="Send_C" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="finS" onserverclick="SendC_ServerClick">Aceptar</button>
```

Por:

```
<asp:Button ID="Send_C" runat="server" Text="Aceptar" CssClass="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="finS" OnClick="SendC_ServerClick" />
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder ahora si valida el Validator  pero no se activa el evento onclick

Comment: Disculpa, respondí a la volada. Reemplaza `onserverclick` por `OnClick`. Acabo de actualizar la respuesta :D

Comment: Hola sigue sin ejecutar el evento

Comment: Coloca un breakpoint, en teoría debería enviar a ejecutar el evento `SendC_ServerClick`

Comment: ya lo depure pero no ejecuta nada asi esta mi button  <asp:Button ID="Send_C" runat="server" Text="Aceptar" CssClass="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="finS" OnClick="SendC_ServerClick" /> y   protected void SendC_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {...}

Comment: ¿Sí te funcionó la respuesta ofrecida?

Comment: me funciona porque si valida asp:RegularExpressionValidator pero ahora ya no ejecuta el evento onclick

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100989/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-huntzberger).